# curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer while accessing http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml

Tags: google-maps

I am facing problem while accessing http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml through code (simplexml_load_file). Its not working from putty console also.

Here are the alternatives i used:

**Option1 >**

$url = 'Above URL?adress=XXXAddress HereXXX';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

Error:Warning: simplexml_load_file(above URL?address=XXXAddress HereXXX): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /data/mgr_3.2.x_5/www/manager/support_scripts/geocode.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "Above URL?address=XXXAddress HereXXX" in /data/mgr_3.2.x_5/www/manager/support_scripts/geocode.php on line 5

bool(false)

**Option 2 >**

Tried it from Server:
]# curl --data "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --verbose http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/

Error:
* Closing connection #0
* Failure when receiving data from the peer
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer

**Curl Details:**

rpm -qa|grep curl

python-pycurl-7.19.0-8.el6.x86_64

curl-7.19.7-36.el6_4.x86_64

libcurl-7.19.7-36.el6_4.x86_64

Recently my code migrated to another server and latest PHP version (5.4.14).

**Tried all solutions given on various sites. I am badly stucked. Please Help out.**

Thanks in advance

Sandip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/ was blocked on the server which caused this issue. Now it is allowed and issue is resolved. Thanks